# Implement multiple sign in with Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

How would I mimic Google's multiple sign-in in my Rails app? Essentially, I need to allow a user to sign in to two or more completely different unlinked accounts and to be able to switch between them without signing out and in each time. The user would have to authenticate with username and password once for each account that he wishes to use, but then subsequently will not have to login for those accounts again until session expiration.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254646/how-would-google-multiple-accounts-sign-in-be-implemented) which guesses at Google's implementation, but I would like some hints as to the best way to approach this in Rails 3.1. I'm using Devise with the [CAS plugin](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable). I assume I would need to override the current_user method to pick the correct account, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Or maybe I can use scopes for this? The issue though is that I need an arbitrary number of accounts logged in simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise does not do this by default and you will have to implement it yourself. I believe the best approach to solve this problem is for you to maintain a signed cookie (`cookies.signed`) with the ids of the users signed in.

Basically, every time a user signs in, you will add his id to the cookie if it isn't there yet (there is a warden callback for every time a user signs in).

Now that you have the ids, you can show the signed in names in the corner like google. When the user clicks in one of the names in the corner, it will pass the id to the server, you will check if the id is in the signed cookie and then switch to that new user using the `sign_in` method in the controller.